# cytoscape system checker fails on mac catalina

Tags: cytoscape

I have installed oracle jdk and updated java (java 8 update 251).  The system checker still fails.

````
############# Cytoscape System Requirements Checker for Mac ##############
Target Cytoscape version: 3.7.2
Your shell is zsh
Compatible OS version found: 10.15
 - Pass: OS Version = 10.15.4
 - Pass: Following Oracle JDK found:

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk
Fail: Java is not reachable.
Try re-installing Java 8.```
````

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things jump out at me.  First, Cytoscape 3.8.0 is the current release, so I would try installing that, and second, Cytoscape 3.8.0 requires Java 11.  Can you give those two things a try and then let us know if the install goes well.

Thanks!

-- scooter